# Use directive or ng-click to change preview in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

So I'm very new to angularjs and have written a function in js that I would like to figure out how to convert to I guess a directive.

I have an image library using ng-repeat to load a series of images. To the right of the images I have a preview block that shows a larger version of the image and updates the information according to the image that is clicked on.

My question is what is the best method to update the preview area when an image is clicked - should I create a directive or use a ng-click on the image to call a function?

Note - all of the data and image are a part of a single object.

This is a smippet of how I was updating it just using js.

```
$('.box').on('click','.mainbox',function(){
    var imgid = this.id;
    $('#preview-img').attr('src', collection[imgid].smImg);
    $('#preview-title').text(collection[imgid].title);
    $('#preview-year').text(collection[imgid].years);
    $('#preview-desc').text(collection[imgid].description);
});
```

[image: sample]

Comment: you can use a unique variable for every photo which will be true or false depends on thumbnail click and a `ng-show` on the preview that will react to that specific variable

Comment: I voted to close because it is too broad. I would personnally handle that issue using the router, where the image editor would be a child state of your images preview.

Comment: I thought to that too but it could get complicated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how your html looks like, but say it looks like this:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="mainbox">
        <img ng-repeat="image in images" src="{{ image.url }} "
             ng-click="setSelectedImage(image)" />
    </div>

    <div id="preview">
        <img src="{{ selectedImage.url }}" />
        <h1>{{ selectedImage.title }}</h1>
        <h3 class="years">{{ selectedImage.years }}</h3>
        <p class="description">{{ selectedImage.description }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And your controller code could look like this:

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.images = [
        { url: "urlOfFirst.png", title: "Image1" .. },
        { url: "urlOfSecond.png", title: "Image2" .. }
    ];

    $scope.setSelectedImage = function(image) {
        $scope.selectedImage = image;
    }
}
```

See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xhdyqab4/) as example

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  I think I was overthinking it in my head.  Thanks!